In a volcanic eruption, can the altitude of the SO2 emission be higher than the ash column?
In the recent volcanic eruptions in South-East Asia, the height/altitude of the ash column is easily available. However, when I tried to simulate/"hindcast" the track of the $SO_2$ emissions using HYSPLIT, the simulation results only reflected satellite data when the stack height was higher than the recorded ash column height. I know that this isn't the most reliable method, but it still scratched my brain. My question is two-fold:

Is it possible for $SO_2$ to rise above and/or be launched at higher altitudes during a volcanic eruption?
If it is possible, what conditions could lead to such circumstances ($SO_2$ altitude higher than ash column height)?


I'd say yes. I recently read a paper on the matter, although it was about spatial extent instead of altitude: https://doi.org/10.1186/s13617-024-00144-x
They show that the spatial extension of the SO2 cloud is not the same that the spatial extension of the ash cloud.
